# how to delete tableView cell iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm new to Objective-C. So I have a Table View with 5 rows in the section (5 cells), and I want to allow the user to delete them, but the app keeps crashing when I click on the delete button. The reason it crashes is because I have 5 rows in the section instead of returning [self.myListItems count] How do I correct this code below while keeping the 5 rows in the section?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source


        [self.myListItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self saveList];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

The error is: Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:]

Comment: Did you reload the TableView after a cell is deleted? And btw why do you want to keep 5 rows even when you delete a cell, which should decrease the number of rows?

Comment: Do you mean you are returning static 5 in `numberOfRowsInSection` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134841/assertion-failure-in-uitableview-endcellanimationswithcontext

Comment: after the method "deleteRowsAtIndexPaths" you need to reload the table view.

Answer (score 5):

In ViewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = NO;
```

And

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //add code here for when you hit delete
        [self.myListItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self saveList];
    }    
}
```

Remember - If you want to remove a row that is the last item in a section you need to remove the whole section instead (otherwise it might get section count wrong and throw this exception).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these:

```
[self.myListItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[tableView beginUpdate];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView endUpdates];

[self saveList];
```

Answer (score 0):

**change the following lines**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
 // Delete the row from the data source
 [tableView beginUpdates]
 [self.myListItems removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
 [tableView endUpdate];
 [self saveList];
}
```